# Having troubles with error in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have few problems with syntax errors here.  Below I have an `alertDialog` with `sharedPreference` and if you are wonder why I have this in a asynctask you can see this [Shared Prefence for alert dialog is making my application non responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796561/shared-prefence-for-alert-dialog-is-making-my-application-non-responsive) But the syntax problem is underneath `installed` in my `onPostExecute` and it says "`installed` cannot be resovled to a variable."  I also have another one under `settings` in my `onPostExecute` that says the same thing as well.  I know this may seem like an easy fix to some people but I find this really complicated for someone like me.  I also advice you look at the link if you have a better method than the `AsyncTask` and `onResume()`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    class asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref_name", 0);
            boolean installed = settings.getBoolean("installed", false);

            return null;
        }}}

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_ad) {

        if(!installed){

            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            alertDialog.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(), null);

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("installed", true);
                    editor.commit();

                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: See my answer in your linked question. Hopefully that will clear it up. I don't know why you were told that you can't do any operations in `onCreate()` that's ridiculous. There is no need for `AsyncTask` in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

`installed` is declared only in `doInBackground`, so it's not visible into `onPostExecute`.

Instead of returning a `String` in `doInBackground` (where in fact you always return `null`), you should return a `boolean` (which would be `installed`), and in `onPostExecute` change the parameter for a `boolean` and test it instead of testing `installed`.

**EDIT**

Taking more time to update my answer :

First, I agree with @codeMagic, you definitely **DON'T** need an `AsyncTask` to do that !

But if you really want to do it this way, here is how you could do it : first, you should change the signature of your `AsyncTask` this way :

```
class asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
```

Then in `doInBackground`, change the return value and instead of returning `null`, return `installed` :

```
@Override
protected boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("pref_name", 0);
        boolean installed = settings.getBoolean("installed", false);

        return installed;
}}}
```

And finally, change the parameter of `onPostExecute` to accept a `boolean` :

```
protected void onPostExecute(boolean installed) {
```

This way, you can test `installed` in your method.

Comment: Actually, the return type should be `Boolean` because of the use of generics.

Answer (score 0):

The `installed` variable is local to the `doInBackground` method, `onPostExecute` cannot see it. You can either add an instance variable:

```
class asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  boolean installed = false;
  @Override protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    installed = true;
  }
}
```

Or, you can change the signature of your Async Task so that it returns a boolean, then simply return installed from `doInBackground` and it will be passed in as the parameter to `onPostExecute`:

```
class asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
  @Override protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    return true;
  }
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean installed) {
  }
}
```